# Singular values of a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, pca

I am trying to get the Singular values of a dataframe using R. The prcomp method displays the Standard Deviation and svd$d displays a vector.
The values displayed are correct. But, I am not sure which one of these is the singular value in this case?
I went through a few documents but they are not pointing to the right direction.

```
iris<-read.table(file.choose(),header=T)
#(i)Plotting singular values
X.pca<-prcomp(iris[,1:4],scale=T) 
X.pca # Displays the Standard Deviations
svd(iris[,1:4])$d # Displays the d values
```

Comment: Is X equal to iris?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have updated accordingly.

Comment: I need to plot the singular values. I was just wondering which value to use. Thanks

Comment: Is standard deviation same as the singular value in data frame?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `components <- prcomp(iris[,1:4)` to get the principal components, you can use `components$sdev` to get to those values as you have done above.

```
data("iris")
iris
components<-prcomp(iris[,1:4]
components$sdev

2.0562689 0.4926162 0.2796596 0.1543862
```

These four values from the PCA are proportional to the 'diagonal matrix', in the equivalent of `svd$d` in a singular value decomposition. The proportion is because `SVD` does not consider the number of samples as the `sdev` does in calculating variance. But these are the standardized singular values from the PCA.

And the resulting data from `components$rotation` using `prcomp()` is equivalent to the `V matrix`:

```
                     PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574
```

If you wanted the `U`  component you could use `components$x`

```
            PC1          PC2          PC3           PC4
  [1,] -2.684125626 -0.319397247  0.027914828  0.0022624371
  [2,] -2.714141687  0.177001225  0.210464272  0.0990265503
  [3,] -2.888990569  0.144949426 -0.017900256  0.0199683897
  [4,] -2.745342856  0.318298979 -0.031559374 -0.0755758166
  [5,] -2.728716537 -0.326754513 -0.090079241 -0.0612585926
  [6,] -2.280859633 -0.741330449 -0.168677658 -0.0242008576
  [7,] -2.820537751  0.089461385 -0.257892158 -0.0481431065
  [8,] -2.626144973 -0.163384960  0.021879318 -0.0452978706
  [9,] -2.886382732  0.578311754 -0.020759570 -0.0267447358...(there is more)
```